# How to keep a Div Opened after its clicked while navigating between pages

Tags: jquery

I was thinking if there is anyway to implement cookies using jquery rather than any server-side languages. Do you think jquery would be an appropriate way for that or the second option ?

I appreciate if you could show me a proper reference or tutorial for that.
Thank you anyway !

Comment: You need to use a cookie, or added php in the link address.

Comment: you're question is too vague, this could refer to a dozen different things. please provide a more clear explanation of your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a complete answer, some guidance.

Use the jQuery cookie plugin. [here](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie).

When the user opens a div, store its state

```
<div id="mydiv1" class="collapsible">
    <h3>Title</h3>
    <div class="contents" style="display:none">Bah!</div>
</div>

$('.collapsible h3').on('click', function(){
    var ref=$(this).parent().attr('id');
    $.cookie(ref, "open");
});
```

And then on document.ready you can pull the value:

```
if ($.cookie("mydiv1")=='open') $('#mydiv1 .contents').show();
```

Of course you would store all your divs' states in one cookie and iterate through them showing the contents that should be show.

Comment: Hey popnoodles, I went through ur sample and I got nothing. Its useful for sure but kind of unrelated to what i was looking for. if possible, give it a chance again. some better samples maybe???

Comment: please provide a more clear explanation of your question. Include HTML